# USSD Gateway implementation

Tags: linux, asterisk, gsm, telecommunication, ussd

I am supposed to develop a USSD gateway for an operator so please help me with the following
-can I use asterisk for this purpose?
-can the asterisk system take alphanumeric characters as user input.

Answer (score 1):

USSD is transported via SS7.

In order to build a USSD gateway you either need a SS7 protocol stack supporting the MAP protocol or a separate SS7 gateway (e.g. MAP-to-SOAP converter) for accessing the SS7 network. This is typically something you purchase from someone who knows what he does.

While it may be possible to (ab)use Asterisk for message routing, I would expect that you get faster results with some message gateway framework or by building an application on your own. Depends on what business logic you actually want to build on top of USSD.

Comment: I want to develop a chat application on top of USSD. So what I want is that a URL in my web server should be called with MSISDN and the content,also I should be able to make a NIUSSD by calling a URL with parameters MSISDN and text. can u please recommend the hardware and software to be used for this. Also they informed me they are using Ericsson's systems.

Comment: I have no idea of the current USSD gateway vendor scene. However, if you happen to be in Europe, I can recommend these people: http://www.materna-communications.de/comm/index.php?id=99&L=1